# Special character breaks jQuery dom creation from HTML string

Tags: jquery, html, dom, special-characters

I am using jQuery to remove unwanted html tags from an input text field. This works fine, however, when a special character is entered as html entities such as `&trade;` (which I want to allow) I get the following error during on the fly DOM creation:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ... `&trade;`

The idea is to get the html string from the text field; create a DOM element from it; then, remove only unwanted tags.

Data like: `<span>My <b>company</b></span>` is scrubbed down to `My <b>company</b>` ...which I expect.

However data entered like: `My <b>company</b> &trade;` breaks

```js
var s = jQuery(this).find('#new-topic').val();
var $s = jQuery(s); //this is where the error occurs
var $elements = $s.find("*").not("b, strong"); //get elements that are not <b> or <strong>

for (var i = $elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var e = $elements[i];
  jQuery(e).replaceWith(e.innerHTML);
}

var finalInput = $s.html();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="new-topic" type="text">
```

Is there anyway to allow special characters in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually being caused when the string captured from the text field isn't wrapped in a tag; for example: `My <b>company</b> &trade;` however `<span>My <b>company</b> &trade;</span>` does work. This was also creating some undesirable behavior when no tags were entered into the text field like: `My company`. To solve this I just always wrap the string in a tag before I create the DOM element: `s = '<test>'+s+'</test>';`

```js
jQuery('#remove-unwanted-tags').on('click', function() {
    var s = jQuery('#new-topic').val();
    console.log('Before removing unwanted tags: ' + s);
    s = '<test>' + s + '</test>'; //added fix
    var $s = jQuery(s); //this is where the error occurs
    var $elements = $s.find("*").not("b, strong"); //get elements that are not <b> or <strong>
    
    for (var i = $elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var e = $elements[i];
        jQuery(e).replaceWith(e.innerHTML);
    }
    
    var finalInput = $s.html();
    console.log('After removing unwanted tags: ' + finalInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="new-topic" type="text">
<input type="button" id="remove-unwanted-tags" value="remove unwanted tags">
```

Not sure if this is the best way to go about property scrubbing unwanted tags but at least it works.